# Multiple of $5$

Tags: probability

If two natural nos. $x,y$ are selected at random then the probability that $x^2+y^2$ is a multiple of 5?

I think they should give a finite set for selecting natural nos. otherwise there are infinite ordered pairs of $x$ and $y$.

Is the question incomplete or am I missing some trick?

Comment: How about the numbers in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ for your finite set?

Comment: The idea is that you are really selecting equivalence classes. $x,y$ may be restricted to 0 to 4 for this problem.

Comment: It is assumed that the probability of $x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ is $\frac15$, and etc.

Comment: So I can select any finite set with $n(S) \gt 2 $  and I will get the same answer? @ParclyTaxel

Comment: @AmanSharma No. You need the cardinality to be exactly 5.

Comment: You can deal with infinite ordered pairs, if you have the right probability for "selecting at random." But you can't get a "nice" probability that makes all numbers equally likely. Stick with the finite set, $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: Why? I have never read about such a thing. Please elaborate. @ParclyTaxel

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I got that but why the cardinality needs to be 5?

Comment: Technically, then, the question is incomplete, because it doesn't tell you what the probability is of selecting any particular natural number.

Comment: @AmanSharma It can't be any five, it has to be five "representatives" - five numbers, no pair of which differ by a multiple of five. The "why" is a bit more complex, and I'll answer that later if nobody else has.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you. I will wait for your answer though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modulo $5$, the residues of $x^2$ take on the values $0, 1, 4, 4, 1$.

So $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 5$ will be true if both residues are $0$ or if one is $1$ and the other is $4$.

This implies the probability is $\frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{5} + 2 \cdot \frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{5} = \frac{9}{25}$

Edit: Let's say we wanted to see the remainder after dividing integer $n$ by integer $k$. This means we could write $n = qk + r$ where $0 \leq r \lt k$ where $q$ is an integer. For example $20$ divided by $7$ can be modeled as $20 = 2 \cdot 7 + 6$.

Then:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x^2+y^2}{5}  &= \frac{(q_1 \cdot 5 + r_1) +(q_2 \cdot 5 + r_2 )}{5} \\
&= \frac{(q_1 + q_2) \cdot 5 + (r_1 + r_2) }{5}  \\
&= (q_1 + q_2) + \dfrac{r_1 + r_2}{5}
\end{align}$$

In other words, after we divide $x^2 + y^2$ by $5$, we'll get some integer $q_1, q_2$ values (that we don't care about), but then we need the sum of the remainders to be divisible by $5$ if $\frac{x^2+y^2}{5}$ is going to be an integer.

Comment: I haven't studied the concept of mod. Can you explain without it? Thank you.

Comment: @AmanSharma It's much easier to just learn the basics of the mod operation. In this case it's like taking the remainder after division. $x^2$ and $y^2$ will both leave behind some remainder after being divided by $5$. If those two remainders sum up to a multiple of $5$, then $x^2 + y^2$ is divisible by $5$ (i.e. leaves no remainder). So we take all the possible remainders they can each leave behind and see which combinations sum to either $0$ or $5$ in this case.

Comment: @AmanSharma Added some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, you can assume that $x$ and $y$ are restricted to the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, as pointed out by [Lord Shark the Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618) in a comment.  Now,
$$z \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \implies z^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$
$$z \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \implies z^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
$$z \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \implies z^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$$
$$z \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \implies z^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$$
$$z \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \implies z^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
Thus, $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ can only happen if
$$x \equiv y \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$
or $x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $y \equiv 2 \pmod 5$, or $x \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ and $y \equiv 2 \pmod 5$, or $x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $y \equiv 3 \pmod 5$, or $x \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ and $y \equiv 3 \pmod 5$, or with the roles of $x$ and $y$ interchanged in the last $4$ cases.

Therefore, this gives a probability of
$$\frac{1}{25}+\frac{4}{25}+\frac{4}{25}=\frac{9}{25}=36\%.$$

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I haven't studied about mod yet. It would be really great if you can explain without it.